# Temporal and predictive GAMs in time series analysis

Tags: time-series, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have several long time series (60 years) of meteorological and soil-related variables. My goal is to analyze the temporal dimension of each variable separately, fill in the gaps in the dataset using Generalized Additive Models (GAMs), and predict their effects on the richness and diversity of herbaceous plants. I have created two predictive models for each variable, 1 predictive and  1 temmporal. This temporal model includes the day of the year as an integer, the year as an integer, and the interaction as a tensor product between the year and the day of the year.
I have also considered incorporating a variable that represents the passage of time for the long-term trend by assigning a value of 1 to the first observation. This adjustment seems to improve the model's performance to some extent.

However, the model that focuses on the temporal dimension struggles to generate accurate predictions due to a lack of information. To address this issue, I am contemplating two approaches. The first is to include additional variables to enhance the predictive capacity of the models, but I am concerned about introducing noise into the temporal dimensions and compromising comparability between models due to varying explanatory variables. The second approach, the one im using, involves creating two separate models: one for predictive purposes, which fills in the missing data, and another specifically designed to analyze trends and seasonality in the filled series. This filled series are the used to predict plan richness.

My doubt comes is if it is logical to make two models or it would be better to make only one with predictive capacity and at the same time to allow the temporal analysis of trend and seasonality; but as I must make one per variable, I am worried about introducing noise in the temporal analysis when comparing model results.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

set.seed(45)
#Fake data, just for workflow ilustration
data <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(2002:2021, each = 365),
  Day= rep(1:365, times = 10),
  Hrelat= rnorm(7300, mean = 50, sd = 10),
  Temperature = rnorm(7300, mean = 15, sd = 2),
  PlantRichness = sample(5:45, 7300, replace = TRUE),
  Time= c(1:7300)
)


data$Hrelat[c(15, 20, 200:300, 350, 2000, 2345:2567, 4530:4900)] = NA
data$PlantRichness[seq(from = 1, to = 7300, by = 5)] <- NA


#'Predictive model: i know using times the model predicts better i just wonder 
#'if it makes sense to make this change in thsi context


pred_mod1 = gam(Hrelat ~ s(Day, bs="cc", k=30) + s(Year, k=10) + s(Hrelat, k=30) + te(Day, Year), data=data, method="REML")
pred_mod2 = gam(Hrelat ~ s(Day, bs="cc", k=30) + s(Time, k=30) + s(Hrelat, k=30)+ te(Day, Year), data=data, method="REML")

#Data filling for NAs
data$Hrelat = ifelse(is.na(data$Hrelat), predict.gam(pred_mod1), data$Hrelat)

#Trend and seasonality analysis
temp_mod = gam(Hrelat ~ s(Day, bs="cc", k=30) + s(Year, k=10), data=data, method="REML")
draw(temp_mod)

# Fit GAM model for predicting PlantRichness
pred_mod_richness = gam(PlantRichness ~ s(Temperature, k = 30) + s(Hrelat) + s(Day) + s(Year) + te(Day, Year), data = data, method="REML")
#Then use it for data filling in Richness
data$Hrelat = ifelse(is.na(data$PlantRichness), predict.gam(pred_mod_richness), data$PlantRichness)
# Fit GAM model for trend and seasonality analysis
temp_mod_richness = gam(PlantRichness ~  s(Day) + s(Year) + te(Day, Year), data = data, method="REML")
```

It's my final degree project, and I want to make sure that this workflow makes sense before presenting it and getting a failing grade.